# Send sessions cookies before taking a screenshot in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, session-cookies

I am trying to take a screenshot of webpage, I have already the session id and token stored in y object (from a previous requests POST).
I would like to use the session token and id (token, JSESSIONID) to login before taking a screenshot of my page :
My logic :

```
def open_url(self, url):
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--incognito')
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')  
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    response = webdriver.request('POST', url, headers=self.headers, data=self.data)
    print(response.text)
    
    driver.get(url)
    driver.add_cookie({"name": "token", "value": self.token})
    driver.add_cookie({"name": "JSESSIONID", "value": self.jsessionid})
    
    driver.get(url)

    
    driver.save_full_page_screenshot('fullpage_gecko_firefox.png')
    driver.quit()
```

I am getting the login page screenshot :/

Thanks a lot for your help